# Mapbox visual for Power BI - visual is not supported and will be deprecated

Tags: powerbi, mapbox

When I am using the Mapbox Visual I get a message that the visual is not supported and will be deprecated.
I am using this visual in the last year and thats the first time that I get that message.
What does that mean?
What about the reports that using this visual?

Comment: The October 21 release includes a preview for Azure Maps. Maybe they are going to push this at the expense of mapbox, I cant see any official notes on this issues though. Poor communication from MS

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for choosing Mapbox for your mapping needs. We have some exciting updates that will be occurring with the Mapbox and Power BI integration.

Over the past few weeks, you may have received a notification `Visual is not supported and will be deprecated...`. Please disregard this message as it does not accurately reflect the status or future plans of the Mapbox Visual for Power BI. Microsoft has removed this notification as of this week.

**We want to clarify that the Power BI integration is not being deprecated.** We are actively working with a trusted partner to ensure the maintenance and ongoing improvement of this integration so it continues to serve our customers in the long run. We will have more details to share in the near future.

In the meantime, for any questions or issues you have regarding Power BI and Mapbox, we recommend you either create an issue in our [open source repository](https://github.com/mapbox/mapboxgl-powerbi/issues) or ask your question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerbi) or the [Power BI forums](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Get-Help-with-Power-BI/ct-p/PBI_GetHelp) to get help from others who may have experienced a similar issue.

Thank you,

Mapbox Support